# Matplotlib: plot pixels without blurring

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to plot a 2x2 array with values in greycsale. If I use the commands

```
plt.imshow(matrix_1, cmap = cm.Greys_r)
plt.show()
```

I got the image below, where the various pixels are not clearly separated. Do you know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify `interpolation='none'`:

```
plt.imshow(matrix_1, cmap = cm.Greys_r, interpolation='none')
```

> **interpolation : string, optional, default: None**
>
> Acceptable values are ‘none’, ‘nearest’, ‘bilinear’, ‘bicubic’,
>   ‘spline16’, ‘spline36’, ‘hanning’, ‘hamming’, ‘hermite’, ‘kaiser’,
>   ‘quadric’, ‘catrom’, ‘gaussian’, ‘bessel’, ‘mitchell’, ‘sinc’,
>   ‘lanczos’
>
> If interpolation is None, default to rc image.interpolation. See also
>   the filternorm and filterrad parameters. If interpolation is ‘none’,
>   then no interpolation is performed on the Agg, ps and pdf backends.
>   Other backends will fall back to ‘nearest’.

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow